# Mouse hover in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm facing a problem of implementing mouse hover event in WPF . First there is no such event in WPF , and second I need to make a similar event to be routed event. I mean, I have a global window , and I want to declare on it something like ButtonBase.MouseHover , so I'll handle this event each time I hover any button on the screen .

Any suggestion .
Best regards
Wasim ...

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563536/unable-to-style-wpf-combobox-on-mouse-hover  the @Tokk's solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 8):

How about MouseEnter ? Serves the same purpose :)

Comment: You wrong. MouseHover in winforms is not just MouseEnter/Leave. This event occures only after specific timeout configurable in Windows (400ms by default in XP). Similar behavior used to highlight hovered file in Explorer or expand context sub-menu.

Comment: Never said it was the same thing - I just suggested the way to do it in WPF

Answer (score 5):

The MouseHover function is split into two parts in WPF: MouseEnter and MouseLeave.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeat event each ms you should use `mouseMove`

Or if you want to execute once when the mouse hover on the object...

you should use `mouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an attached property and then do exactly that.

If its just on buttons, you could always specify custom tooltip stuff, couldn't you?