# Unable to style WPF ComboBox on Mouse Hover

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Does anyone know how to style the background property of a WPF ComboBox when a mouse is hovering on top of it?

[image]

I cannot get rid of the blue-ish button like background off the ComboBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work.Its because of the default control template of ComboBox.You may need to override the default template for this behavior.Have a look at

[MouseOver highlighting style returning to default after a second (Caused by Aero?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250622/217880)

http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en/blend/thread/b210978c-24e8-431b-916b-a40a752b990c

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/a18891e9-8879-4819-9679-247341782f60

Answer (score 4):

You can style it like anything else:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="HoverBox">
   <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

usage:

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource HoverBox}" ... />
```

And at the top of your UserControl/ Window you have to place the style:

```
<UserControl...>
    <UserControl.Resources>

         <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" x:Key="HoverBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </UserControl.Resources>

[CONTENT HERE]

</UserControl>
```

Comment: I put the style inside the combo box as you have written. But it gives me an exception on the x:Key saying "Key attribute can be used only on a tag contained in an IDictionary type property"

Comment: thanks for the effort. I did as you said, but the Combo box still gets the old button background.

Comment: You can set IsEditable to true...perhaps this is what you want?